# Read Until usage in robot framework with constant changing prompt

Tags: robotframework

I'm new to robot framework. I'm trying to create a Keyword in my suite to login to DUT, run a command and fetch the output. but the prompt of the DUT is constantly changing. Following is the keyword and also the command output in DUT.

Keyword snippet:

```
Write    show table sys ClassOfService
${output}=    Read Until Regexp    admin@0-9 .*\>
```

command output in DUT:

`admin@0-9 19:36:44> show table sys ClassOfService
profileXml "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><cos version=\"1.0\">    <PublicIdentifiers>
</PublicIdentifiers> \t\t\t </cos>";
[ok][2020-04-11 19:36:45]
admin@0-9 19:36:45>`

But it is always getting timeout. Please let me know if I'm missing something.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression looks good, but in Robot Framework the > must have the \ escaped with another \. Look at the example for [Read Until Regexp](http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/SSHLibrary.html#Read%20Until%20Regexp). Your final command should be:

```
Write    show table sys ClassOfService
${output}=    Read Until Regexp    admin@0-9 .*\\>
```

Comment: Thanks, Helio. I did the changes as per ur comment. but it was timing out. when I debug further, I found that there may be a page size limitation issue. since the command output maybe sometimes huge length. is there any configuration parameter for the same? 


    1) No match found for '%' in 1 minute
Output:
profileXml "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><cos version=\"1.0\"><isVmSu--More--.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I only see the possibility to increase the timeout.

Comment: Thanx Helios, the problem is solved after increasing the width and height of the connection.

    Set Client Configuration   width=2500   height=2500